# Google Analytics hitCallback with timeout

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I was checking out [Google Analytics Guides](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#hitcallback) and saw this code:

```
// Gets a reference to the form element, assuming
// it contains the id attribute "signup-form".
var form = document.getElementById('signup-form');

// Adds a listener for the "submit" event.
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

  // Prevents the browser from submiting the form
  // and thus unloading the current page.
  event.preventDefault();

  // Sends the event to Google Analytics and
  // resubmits the form once the hit is done.
  ga('send', 'event', 'Signup Form', 'submit', {
    hitCallback: function() {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

Then it says "If (for whatever reason) the analytics.js library fails to load, the hitCallback function will never run." And it provide a solution as below:

```
// Gets a reference to the form element, assuming
// it contains the id attribute "signup-form".
var form = document.getElementById('signup-form');

// Adds a listener for the "submit" event.
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

  // Prevents the browser from submiting the form
  // and thus unloading the current page.
  event.preventDefault();

  // Creates a timeout to call `submitForm` after one second.
  setTimeout(submitForm, 1000);

  // Keeps track of whether or not the form has been submitted.
  // This prevents the form from being submitted twice in cases
  // where `hitCallback` fires normally.
  var formSubmitted = false;

  function submitForm() {
    if (!formSubmitted) {
      formSubmitted = true;
      form.submit();
    }
  }

  // Sends the event to Google Analytics and
  // resubmits the form once the hit is done.
  ga('send', 'event', 'Signup Form', 'submit', {
    hitCallback: submitForm
  });
});
```

I can understand the code above. But what follows next confused me:

```
function createFunctionWithTimeout(callback, opt_timeout) {
  var called = false;
  function fn() {
    if (!called) {
      called = true;
      callback();
    }
  }
  setTimeout(fn, opt_timeout || 1000);
  return fn;
}

// Gets a reference to the form element, assuming
// it contains the id attribute "signup-form".
var form = document.getElementById('signup-form');

// Adds a listener for the "submit" event.
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

  // Prevents the browser from submiting the form
  // and thus unloading the current page.
  event.preventDefault();

  // Sends the event to Google Analytics and
  // resubmits the form once the hit is done.
  ga('send', 'event', 'Signup Form', 'submit', {
    hitCallback: createFunctionWithTimeout(function() {
      form.submit();
    })
  });
});
```

My understanding is, in that last block of code, if the analytics.js library fails to load, the hitCallback function will not run, which means the setTimeout() will not run. So the last block of code seems not having the functionality as the second block of code.

Did I miss anything? Or this is what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what needs clearing up first here is what Google means when they say `hitCallback` fails.  This snippet from their [documentation on the property](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#hitCallback) sheds a little light on that:

> You may want to avoid using hitcallBack to execute code that is critical to your application since it's possible it may not get called in rare cases (e.g. if the server doesn't respond or analytics.js fails to load). In this case you can set a timeout to ensure execution.

After reading the question initially, I thought if the `ga` object sends a hit then surely `hitCallback` has to work, that this scenario had to be all or nothing.  From the sound of it, Google is only warning about rare blips in the system or obscure load failures that occur between the hit send, and the callback functionality. What I'm understanding from this statement is that the `ga` object is always going to employ `hitCallback`, but there's a small chance that a response will never come back from the server.  It's because of these scenarios that it's recommended not to have mission-critical code depending on this property.

To explain the code above, the setups in blocks 2 and 3 accomplish the same goal with different levels of abstraction.  In the 2nd block, we have a function:

```
function submitForm() {
    if (!formSubmitted) {
      formSubmitted = true;
      form.submit();
    }
  }
```

that, at the time the form's submit event is fired, is called once in a `setTimeout` and once in the `hitCallback`.  So if the latter never gets a response, the 1-second delay on the former will submit the form without depending on a response.

The 3rd block wraps the `setTimeout` functionality in a function that is run when the javascript is first loaded:

```
function createFunctionWithTimeout(callback, opt_timeout) {
  var called = false;
  function fn() {
    if (!called) {
      called = true;
      callback();
    }
  }
  setTimeout(fn, opt_timeout || 1000);
  return fn;
}
```

In this case, `createFunctionWithTimeout` is calculated at the time the javascript is read, and the function that is passed in will either be called by `hitCallback` upon returning from analytics, or be called by the `setTimeout` from before.

Since `hitCallback` works as a callback, we can verify this by using event listener callbacks as a test.  Take this code for example:

```js
// Same function as above
function createFunctionWithTimeout(callback, opt_timeout) {
  var called = false;
  function fn() {
    if (!called) {
      called = true;
      callback();
    }
  }
  setTimeout(fn, opt_timeout || 1000);
  return fn;
}

// The createFunctionWithTimeout will be calculated initially when it loads
// If you don't press the button for 2 seconds, the alert will still pop up
// If you press the button before 2 seconds passes, you'll see the popup earlier
$('#btn').click(createFunctionWithTimeout(function() { 
 alert("Hello!"); 
  }, 2000)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' id='btn' value='test' />
```

So whether you go with the 2nd or 3rd block depends on how much you want to abstract the `setTimeout` functionality.  Google's documentation recommends the 3rd case if you plan to use the function a lot as this cuts down on duplicating the code, but ultimately, both accomplish the goal.

Comment: There are a lot of cases where the `analytics.js` library may fail to load (e.g. a variety of network errors), but the most common case by far is if the user has a browser extension that is blocking Google Analytics. If `analytics.js` fails to load, then the global `ga()` function basically does nothing, so the `hitCallback` will never be invoked.

Comment: @PhilipWalton That's kind of what I thought would happen if `analytics.js` didn't load since the `ga` object is dependent on that.  The way the documentation sounded to me was the `ga()` function would fire but `hitCallback` may not get a response, but maybe it just reads funny to me.  Having both be rendered useless makes more sense, as you've pointed out.